# OAuth client implementation w/ multiple resources, multiple auth servers

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to understand OAuth best practice implementation strategies for systems requiring access to protected resources backed by different authorization servers. The default answer is to use the access tokens provided by each authorization service and write the logic to store them on an as-needed basis, but the use case of systems requiring multiple, federated protected resources seems common enough that there might be a protocol/framework-level solution. If so, I haven't been able to find it.

Here's a hypothetical example to clarify:

I'm a user with an account on Dropbox, Google Drive, and Boxx. I'd like to make a backend API to report the total number of files I own across all three systems, i.e., `Result = FileCount(Dropbox) + FileCount(Drive) + FileCount(Boxx)`. How to I organize the system in such a way that I can easily manage authorizations? A few cases:

- **Single-account:** If I only have, say, a Drive account, the setup is easy. There's one protected resource (my folders), one authorization server (Google), and so I only have one token to think about. By changing the authorization endpoints and redefining the FileCount function, I can make this app work for any storage client I care about (Dropbox, Google, Boxx).
- **Multi-account:** If I want to aggregate data from each protected resource, I now need three separate authorizations, because each protected resource is managed by a separate authorization server. AFAIK, I can't "link" these clients to use a single authorization server. As a result, if I have N protected resources backed by N authorization servers, I'll have N access tokens to manage for a given request/session. Assuming this is true, what provisions do software frameworks provide to handle this (any example in any language is fine)? It just seems too common of a problem not to be abstracted.

The closest related question I can find is probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724890/oauth-token-for-multiple-services). The accepted answer seems completely reasonable: one application should not be able to masquerade as another without explicit consent. What I'm looking for is (I think) slightly different: some standard methodology/framework/approach to managing multiple simultaneous access tokens per session. I've also wondered about the possibility of an independent authorization server that can proxy the others as needed and manage the token bookkeeping (still requiring user consent for each), but I think this amounts to the same thing.

Thanks in advance.